# Rendering a colored plane with NO shading creates weird pixels at borders?

Tags: rendering, transparency, color, antialiasing

I turn to you with a question about Blender (`2.90`) rendering behaviour.

I am rendering a colored plane only (literally, that's it - no shading, plugging the "image texture" node right into the surface node of material output), so quite a simple setup. However, when rendering the plane, Blender creates some weirdly colored pixels at some locations on the plane's borders (see image). Note that these are not visible in the viewport and only show after rendering.

I am rendering with Cycles, transparent RGBA, to 16bit png. I already tried setting Film `->` Pixel Filter `->` Gaussian to the smallest size possible (`0.01px`,  I need to render it without Anti-Aliasing), and also set "Alpha Clip" in the material section. I experimented with Eevee and also with different render resolutions (ranging from `250p` to `1080p`), alas to no avail. I tried setting the backside of the plane to another color, but that didn't help either. I also tried setting the number of samples in both viewport and renderer to 1, which didn't help either.

Full plane:

[image]

Artefacts (zoomed):

[image]

Does somebody have an idea what is going on here? Any hints appreciated!

[image] and the texture that is applied to the plane: https://i.stack.imgur.com/StzMT.jpg

Comment: Untested, but it looks alpha premult.  Note that you're getting antialiasing if you're using more than 1 sample for your renders, so you might consider setting samples to 1.

Comment: Please attach your simplified blend file to see your setup. Use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and paste given code into your question.

Comment: Thanks guys, Nathan: I tried rendering with 1 sample already, same results. @vklidu: I have updated the question with the .blend file and the texture that is applied to the plane. There's also a script that renders the image from the viewpoint above, clearly showing the artefacts.

Comment: I suppose lights in the scene are not relevant to result (also script gave me an error). One note - texture like this is better "packed" into blend file. Since links are not permanent. This site is maintained to be knowledge base, so others can find answers for their issues. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using **Repeat** extrapolation in *Image Node*.
Those pixels are just texture's pixels from opposite side of texture.
Set **Extend** instead.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that indeed solved the problem. Such a small setting, causing such havoc. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome :) I know, we all have those ... :)